# Explain which partitions of $n$ does the coefficient of $x^n$ count in the following...

Tags: combinatorics, euler-product

$\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^3}(1+x^2+x^4)$.
I've expanded out the 2 fractions with Taylor series then found that it equals $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ but I'm not sure if this is right/ what I can say from this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before make the taylor series one can observe that $1+x^2 + x^4 = 1+ 2x^2 + x^4 - x^2 = (1+x^2)^2 - x^2 = (1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)$. Thus the equation is $$\frac{(1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)}{(1-x)\cdot (1-x)(1+x+x^2)} = \frac{1-x+x^2}{(1-x)^2}  $$

Comment: + your taylor expansion is correct as I see.

Comment: Note that if you want $x+2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + \ldots = \sum nx^n$, that's equal to
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Comment: @dust05 Thanks this simplifies the expansion nicely. For the specific "Explain which partitions of n does the coefficient count" From the result I have I'm not sure from my undertsanding what I can conclude from this?

Comment: Frankly I don't understand the sentence. what do you mean by "which partition of $n$ does the coefficient count"?

Answer (score 0):

From the product, it counts the number of partitions that use:

- any number of 1's
- 0, 1, or 2 of 2's
- any number of 3's
- no other terms.